# Is there a way to UNION ALL two queries and remove repeated rows

Tags: sql, postgresql, union

I'm working with permissions, I have the table `user_screens` that store the permissions of the `users`;

I have the table `segment_screens` that define which screens a user can have permissions.

I need get all the screens that is in `segment_screens`. If `segment_screen.screen_id` is in table `user_screens`, take the row of the table `user_screens`, if `segment_screen.screen_id` is not in the table `user_screens` I need to return the id null and the permissions as false.

I try this way:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
          user_screens.id,
          s.description,
          user_screens.screen_id,
          user_screens.allow_read,
          user_screens.allow_create,
          user_screens.allow_update,
          user_screens.allow_delete
          FROM
          (SELECT id,
            screen_id,
            allow_read,
            allow_create,
            allow_update,
            allow_delete
          FROM user_screens
          WHERE user_id = 1
          UNION ALL SELECT
                      NULL AS id,
                      s.id,
                      'f' :: BOOLEAN AS allow_read,
                      'f' :: BOOLEAN AS allow_create,
                      'f' :: BOOLEAN AS allo_update,
                      'f' :: BOOLEAN AS allow_delete
          FROM users u
          LEFT JOIN user_companies uc ON uc.user_id = u.id
          LEFT JOIN companies c ON c.id = uc.company_id
          LEFT JOIN segments seg ON seg.id = c.segment_id
          LEFT JOIN segment_screens segscreen ON segscreen.segment_id = seg.id
          LEFT JOIN screens s ON s.id = segscreen.screen_id) user_screens
          LEFT JOIN screens s ON s.id = user_screens.screen_id
          ORDER  BY s.description ASC
```

But this way when I have a row in `user_screen` and in `segment_screen` I'm taking this two records and I need only the row that is in the `user_screens` with the rows that is not in user_screens but is in segment_screens.

This is my result:

[image]
In yellow is the record that I need to keep and the record down is the element that I don't need but is already in `user_screens`.

How can I do this?

@Edit:

Tried with `DISTINCT ON` and `ORDER BY`:

```
`SELECT DISTINCT ON (screen_id) screen_id,
          user_screens.id,
          s.description,
          user_screens.screen_id,
          user_screens.allow_read,
          user_screens.allow_create,
          user_screens.allow_update,
          user_screens.allow_delete
          FROM
          (SELECT id,
            screen_id,
            allow_read,
            allow_create,
            allow_update,
            allow_delete
          FROM user_screens
          WHERE user_id = ?
          order by screen_id, (id is not null) desc
          UNION ALL SELECT
                      NULL AS id,
                      s.id,
                      'f' :: BOOLEAN AS allow_read,
                      'f' :: BOOLEAN AS allow_create,
                      'f' :: BOOLEAN AS allo_update,
                      'f' :: BOOLEAN AS allow_delete
          FROM users u
          LEFT JOIN user_companies uc ON uc.user_id = u.id
          LEFT JOIN companies c ON c.id = uc.company_id
          LEFT JOIN segments seg ON seg.id = c.segment_id
          LEFT JOIN segment_screens segscreen ON segscreen.segment_id = seg.id
          LEFT JOIN screens s ON s.id = segscreen.screen_id) user_screens
          LEFT JOIN screens s ON s.id = user_screens.screen_id
          ORDER BY s.description ASC
      `
```

Answer (score 2):

This are not duplicates.  But if you want to keep one record per some value in a column, you can use `distinct on`:

```
select distinct on (screen_id) . . .
from . . .
order by screen_id, (id is not null) desc;
```

Comment: the order by is optional?

Comment: @bla . . . The `order by` is NOT optional.  It is needed when you use `distinct on`.  If you want the final results in a different order, then put this in a subquery or CTE and put your ordering in the outer query.

Comment: ok, i'm receiving a syntax error, i put what i tried in a edit